# Exibição de dados em uma tabela com foreach

Tags: php, html, array, foreach, table

Estou com problemas na página de resultados, as outras estão funcionando corretamente, o objetivo é imprimir a aprovação ou a reprovação dos alunos na tabela usando `foreach` no PHP.

**Erro:**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

```
<?php            

$nota1 = $_POST["matematica"];
$nota2 = $_POST["portugues"];
$nota3 = $_POST["quimica"];
$nota4 = $_POST["fisica"];
$nota5 = $_POST["geografia"];
$nota6 = $_POST["historia"];

$notas = [$nota1, $nota2, $nota3, $nota4, $nota5, $nota6];

function calculaAprovacao($nota){
    foreach($nota as $lista){
    if($lista >= 60){

        return "Aprovado";
    }else{

        return "Reprovado";
    }
    }
}


?>

<?php include "cabecalho.php"?>


<table border="1px">
    <?php foreach(calculaAprovacao($notas) as $aprovacao): ?>
    <tr>
        <th>Matemática</th>
        <td><?php echo $aprovacao[0]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Português</th>
        <td><?php echo $aprovacao[1]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th>Química</th>
        <td><?php echo $aprovacao[2]; ?></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
            <th>Física</th>
            <td><?php echo $aprovacao[3]; ?></td>
        <tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Geografia</th>
            <td><?php echo $aprovacao[4]; ?></td>
        <tr>

    <tr>
        <th>História</th>
        <td><?php echo $aprovacao[5]; ?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A dúvida é como preencher a tabela com os resultados de aprovado ou reprovado com foreach usando a função, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O uso do `foreach` não parece fazer sentido aí. no HTML você está repetindo todas as 6 linhas (`<tr>`) então não tem porque usar o `foreach`. E daí também não tem porque usar o `foreach` dentro da função que pega o texto de aprovação, já que está executando tudo individualmente (na verdade acho que esta função não deveria ter `foreach` mesmo). Na forma atual qualquer uso de *loop* é uma complicação desnecessária. Se quer usar um *loop* então faça um código adequado. Vou mostrar as duas formas.

Seguindo seu algoritmo sem *loop*:

```
<?php
$nota1 = $_POST["matematica"];
$nota2 = $_POST["portugues"];
$nota3 = $_POST["quimica"];
$nota4 = $_POST["fisica"];
$nota5 = $_POST["geografia"];
$nota6 = $_POST["historia"];

$notas = [$nota1, $nota2, $nota3, $nota4, $nota5, $nota6];

function calculaAprovacao($nota){
    return $nota >= 60 ? "Aprovado" : "Reprovado";
}
include "cabecalho.php"
?>

<table border="1px">
     <tr>
        <th>Matemática</th>
        <td><?php echo calculaAprovacao($notas[0]); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Português</th>
        <td><?php echo calculaAprovacao($notas[1]); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th>Química</th>
        <td><?php echo calculaAprovacao($notas[2]); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Física</th>
        <td><?php echo calculaAprovacao($notas[3]); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Geografia</th>
        <td><?php echo calculaAprovacao($notas[4]); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>História</th>
        <td><?php echo calculaAprovacao($notas[5]); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/ForEachTemplate.php).

Se realmente quer usar o `foreach` tem como fazer e até recomendo que faça desta forma. Mas precisa mudar um pouco o código, ficaria assim:

```
<?php            
$notas = array( "Matemática" => $_POST["matematica"], "Português" => $_POST["portugues"],
                "Química" => $_POST["quimica"], "Física" => $_POST["fisica"], 
                "Geografia" => $_POST["geografia"], "História" => $_POST["historia"]);

function calculaAprovacao($nota){
    return $nota >= 60 ? "Aprovado" : "Reprovado";
}
include "cabecalho.php"
?>
<table border="1px">
<?php foreach($notas as $disciplina => $nota) { ?>
     <tr>
        <th><?php echo $disciplina; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo calculaAprovacao($nota); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/ForEachTemplate2.php).

Dá para fazer isto de forma até melhor mas provavelmente teria que mudar a estrutura da sua aplicação, não bastaria mudar só este trecho de código.

E alguma coisa me diz que este `<th>` está em lugar errado também, o que precisaria mudar este código HTML.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou legal. Era exatamente isso que pensei.

Answer (score 3):

O que você está fazendo errado é que `foreach` itera sobre um array e o retorno do seu método `calculaAprovacao` é um boolean.

Se você quer usar deste jeito, terá de criar um array dentro do método e adicionar `true` ou `false` para cada iteração dentro do método e retornar o array.

```
function calculaAprovacao($nota){
    $resultados = array();
    foreach($nota as $lista){
        $resultados[] = ($lista >= 60) ? "Aprovado" : "Reprovado";
    }
    return $resultados;
}
```

Terá de alteração a chamada de impressão também, por exemplo:

```
<th>Matemática</th>
<td><?php echo $aprovacao; ?></td>
```

Comment: Luis nesse caso pega somente o valor de aprovados, preciso imprimir aprovado ou reprovado na tabela, é possível facilitar do jeito que coloquei a tabela dentro do foreach ?

Comment: @Thiago atualizei o código, tinha esquecido que era uma mensagem "personalizada".

Comment: Beleza valeu cara.

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa usar `foreach` para gerar esta tabela.

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
function calculaAprovacao($notas) {
    // "resultados" retornará um array contendo "Aprovado" ou "Reprovado" 
    // nos índices na mesma ordem do parâmetro "$notas"
    $resultados = [];

    foreach($notas as $nota) {
        $resultados[] = ($nota >= 60 ? "Aprovado" : "Reprovado");
    }

    return $resultados;
}
```

No seu HTML seria só imprimir os itens do array retornado:

```html
<table border="1px">
    <?php $aprovacao = calculaAprovacao($notas); ?>
    <tr>
        <th>Matemática</th>
        <td><?php echo $aprovacao[0]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Português</th>
        <td><?php echo $aprovacao[1]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th>Química</th>
        <td><?php echo $aprovacao[2]; ?></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
            <th>Física</th>
            <td><?php echo $aprovacao[3]; ?></td>
        <tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Geografia</th>
            <td><?php echo $aprovacao[4]; ?></td>
        <tr>

    <tr>
        <th>História</th>
        <td><?php echo $aprovacao[5]; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo aqui.